# Run method only if exists

Tags: function, flutter, dart

How can I run a method only if it exists?
I tried the following but it didn't work:

`widget.onChangeHandler ?? widget.onChangeHandler(selectedItem);`

Here's the full code:

```
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function onChangeHandler;
  MyWidget({this.onChangeHandler});

  @override
  MyWidgetState createState() => MyWidgetState();
}

class MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  void onTap(dynamic selectedItem) {
    widget.onChangeHandler(selectedItem); // Here's where I call the method
  }
  // ...
```

Comment: What do you mean `only if it exists` ?

Comment: @void The parent widget has a parameter `onChangeHandler` which is not required. What I want to do, is run `onChangeHandler` only if a function was passed into the argument.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal reproducible code ?  @Jessica

Comment: `widget.onChangeHandler?.call(selectedItem)`

Comment: @jamesdlin Nice! Can you explain the `call`?